# Using "Visual Studio code" with interactive Powershell window like Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio code so thanks in advance for the help.

I often use the PowerShell ISE with an interactive PowerShell window. I open it, type a few commands, then run a script (such as opening a PowerShell session with Office 365) and then type a few more commands.

Is there any way to do the same thing with Visual Studio code? I see a way to run scripts and debug them but not have them complete but the PowerShell window still stay around so I can continue working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to convert to answer, since this is a bit too much for comments:

Go to settings > user settings and change "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" to:

```
"C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
```

**Ctrl + Shift + `** opens the terminal. Using the **+** button on the terminal window you can launch additional powershell instances.

Also there's an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher) that allows for launching several different terminals under the same VSCode process (cmd,powershell,bash,etc). Minor nuance, shells are being started with the same permissions VSCode has, but you can re-elevate once inside the shell.

References:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10893

Edit: but I would say its not really convenient, terminal takes away too much space on the screen (well, unless you have like 2k or 4k display), so I use powershell + vscode.

Comment: Thanks very much! that worked!

I hoped I would also be able to run/debug the script from that same terminal. I do that  regularly with the ISE, run a script and then afterward types of additional commands in the same window where ran it (if it's not working correctly, I will often do that to try out what commands I would need before adding it to the script). It's helpful if it's the same window any actions performed by the script are there and variables (vs. another window the script did not run in). 

Is that expected behavior or possible?  If not possible, I will make do.

Comment: well, I'm not sure I understand you correctly, take a look here: https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2015/12/27/debugging-powershell-script-with-visual-studio-code/ @BobbyDore also this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Comment: Thanks, accepted as answer. 

Perhaps I wasn't clear before, sorry about that. My intent is to run a script in the debugger and when it finishes have the powershell session (and the powershell window into which I can type commands) remain around so I can keep using it. Is that possible?

Comment: @BobbyDore Not until [this pull request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/pull/368) for editor services is merged, and support is added to VSCode.  In other words, no not yet but it's coming.